# Laravel scheduled tasks being triggered multiple times

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a cron job scheduled in laravel.

> $schedule->command('my:command')->everyFiveMinutes();

It was running perfectly but after maintenance, cron job is being triggered multiple times occasionally. This behavior is not found at each run of the cron job.

This was being triggered once in every 5 minutes correctly. Due to our DB server maintenance, I had to put the website also on maintenance mode using `php artisan down`. Once the maintenance was over, I did `php artisan up`. Ever since then, occasionally(once a day or once in 2 days) cron job is being triggered like 5 or 6 times instead of once. Then in the next run, it gets back to normal (runs only once).

Laravel version 5.4 , php version of the server 7.0.

Comment: did you try to check your crontabs?  use crontab -l | grep -i "my:command"

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you ever figure out the possible reason in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that Laravel tasks will not be triggered in maintenance mode (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#maintenance-mode).

Make sure that the task you are running takes less than five minutes to finish, if you have long-running tasks, then they might be triggered multiple times because of the allocated time for these tasks which is not sufficient.

Just keep it in mind that Laravel will not stop the tasks from being run, so it can't stop the task and run it again, this is the sysadmin duty to check if the task will be run within the given time frame.

Comment: Yes, it is a small task. I created a table with timetamps columns that adds an entry for each run of the job to monitor the created_at column.  It turned out that, cron job for this particular instance (where it is being called many times), is running before it's supposed to run. For example: at 11.06 am cron job ran 5 times. created_at column in the table indicated 2019-06-25 11:10:29 and  2019-06-25 11:10:28 . And again, this job ran exactly at 11:10 am and created_at column was 2019-06-25 11:10:02.

Comment: Are you sure that your `timestamps` are synced with the server time? so, you are not using a different time-zone in your PHP than the server one.

Comment: How do I check that? If you could please assist. Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: No problem, just make sure that your server has the correct timezone, I have no idea about your server, so you have to google it.
After that make sure that Laravel's `timezone` matches your server's one, this can be done through `config/app.php` by setting the correct timezone in `timezone` key.

Comment: My server time is set to BST, where as laravel timezone parameter is UTC. Could this be causing issues? These were the configurations from the beginning and issue has been occuring only for past one month after I did a php artisan down and php artisan up